# How to get the URL of an action method in ASP.NET MVC using AJAX?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

How can I make an AJAX call to retrieve the URL of controller's action method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you write the JS in your view you can write something like this.

`var ajaxUrl = <%= Url.Action("NameOfAction") %>`

this will put the url into your javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

Just inject the url into the javascript using the UrlHelper:

```
<script>

var url = '<%: Url.Action("ActionName") %>';

$.get(url);

</scrtip>
```